# Using an already setup RAID 1 array on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, hardware, raid

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS on a separate HDD to dual boot with Window 7 x64. My Windows install is on an SSD and my system includes two 3TB Seagate drives in Raid 1. Raid is provided by the motherboard's Intel chipset.  The SSD is on a different Sata chip by AsMedia. The mobo is an AsRock Z77-Pro4.

In Windows, I have the Intel Storage software that checks the Raid array for synch problems and any other issues.  This works fine.

What I would like to ask is whether that same Raid array can be seen as one drive from Ubuntu. As it stands, Ubuntu recognises that I have TWO separate 3TB HDD, named /sda and /sdb.

Is there a way for Ubuntu to recognise that both these drives are in fact supposed to be seen as one and keep them in sync if I change or update something in one of them?  Will the change be reflected in both of them once the array is accessed through Windows?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is known as a [Fake Raid](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/FakeRaidHowto).  If you install the `dmraid` package, it will recognize the array and create a device in /dev/mapper/ that you can use to access it correctly.  Be sure to use that device, and not the individual disks.